# Python return a string by json

Tags: python, unicode, unicode-string, python-unicode

I got a problem, first I made a api that accepts a post request,
then responds with JSON as a result.

Post request data had been encoded, I accepted the post data, and got the data
rightly, then I response with the new data in JSON format.

But when I returned the JSON, I found that the string is unicode format, e.g.

```
{
  'a':'\u00e3\u0080'
}
```

but, I want to get a format like this:

```
{
  'a':"ã"
}
```

I want this format because I found that this unicode format didn't work well in IE8.

Yes, IE8.

What can I do for this issue?
Thanks!

Comment: Example code? Python encoding string?

Comment: What does "didn't work well in IE8" mean? The first result is acceptable if that's the correct value.

Comment: in IE8, through I decode my string, but it will still display as unicode format, decode didn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using standard library `json` module, specifying `ensure_ascii=False` give you what you want.

For example:

```
>>> print json.dumps({'a': u'ã'})
{"a": "\u00e3"}
>>> print json.dumps({'a': u'ã'}, ensure_ascii=False)
{"a": "ã"}
```

According to [`json.dump` documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.dump):

> If **ensure_ascii** is True (the default), all non-ASCII characters in the
>   output are escaped with \uXXXX sequences, and the result is a str
>   instance consisting of ASCII characters only. If ensure_ascii is
>   False, some chunks written to fp may be unicode instances. This
>   usually happens because the input contains unicode strings or the
>   encoding parameter is used. ...

---

BTW, what do you mean "*unicode format didn't work well in IE8,*" ?

Comment: actually, till now, my response works well in all explorers, but IE8.

Comment: thanks for your help, PS, why ensure_ascii's default value is True, I think it should be False.

Comment: @matthewxiang, I don't know the reason why `True` is the default.